# can we run multiple web sites from the one Woocommerce Store?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

can you run multiple web sites from the one Woocommerce Store?

Also managed everything from one admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce is a plugin for wordpress and cannot run multiple stores. However you may want to run wordpress as a multisite installation and for each site, 
you install plugin and can control all three stores from one wordpress admin.

However i will recommend Magento, as its capable of multi store.
Hope it helps

Comment: [1]: http://www.brihaspatitech.com/blog/wordpress-multisite-plugin-woocommerce/
  [2]: https://woomultistore.com/
  [3]: https://woomultistore.com/documentation/

Comment: I know woocommerce is a wordpress plugin. But after creating multisite/Network in wordpress. 
Can we manage like product,stock,orders,customers from one admin panel for all linked sites ?

Can we display products over all sites from main site added in woocommerce?